# How to pass WooCommerce order object to custom JS on clicking order button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a WooCommerce custom payment gateway and want to run some JS when the user clicks the order button, but I need that JS to have access to the order object.  So far, what I have is something like this:

```
    public function __construct() {   
        // constructor stuff, yadda yadda yadda

        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', array( $this, 'checkout_click_handler' ) );
    }

    
    public function checkout_click_handler() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">                
            jQuery(document).on( "updated_checkout", function(){
                // do JS stuff here, but no access to order object
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass the `$order` object into that action callback, then I could stringify it as JSON to pass it to the JS.

UPDATE:  Ok, I realized I am thinking about this the wrong way, although a similar problem still exists.  That function `checkout_click_handler()` is added to the HTML long before the user fills out their information and clicks the order button.  What I really need is for the `process_payment()` function to be able to somehow inject new HTML once it receives the order details.  Is that possible?

Comment: With `woocommerce_after_checkout_form` hook, there is no order object yet on checkout! You can't get the order Object on checkout…You can only get  cart or session data

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yeah that's what i realized (see UPDATE above).  so, is there a solution, or is this not possible?

Comment: BTW, gateway classes do get the order object in their `process_payment()` function, which i guess is technically _after_ the order is submitted.  this is where i would need to do whatever it is that i need to do...